# dynamoDB fetch latest event by date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following `table` in `dynamoDB`:

```
id(int) | version(int) | data(json) | created(date)
```

I want to retrieve the latest record for the given `id`, in SQL terms I like to do :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id="my_id" ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Is this possible in `dynamoDB` and if so, how can I go about it?

The only solution I could think of is to retrieve all data and filter by date programmatically, obviously, This is very costly, and I am trying to avoid it.

Comment: What does your table look like? Which are the key attributes? You design a NoSQL data model based on the access patterns and then store the data in a way that matches them, not the other way around.

Comment: @Maurice I guess I'm still new to it, effectively, id is the hash and version is the version the other two fields are just "extras".
I probably need to re-design the entire table...

Comment: If you want to sort by something (or select based on its sorted value) then it goes into your sort key. If your version values are sortable and increasing then you can use the version value already to find the latest and ignore the time.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I think you are looking for a solution in the "RDB" field that don't match the freedom of data modeling that DynamodB gives you.

I managed to save a completely separated record that is the "latest version" of the data, and using a suitable sorting key, you can directly get the latest data in a single query and in "blazingly fast" (:D) fashion.

Simply add a chunk of code after every put command (or update, or upsert) that update  the single "latestVersion" sorting key.

In your example you don't show which are the Partition Key and the Sorting Key, but I imagine a model like that:

```
id(int - Partition Key) | version(int Sorting Key) | data(json) | created(date)
```

If you switch the version type and go for something like:

```
id(int - Partition Key) | version(string Sorting Key) | data(json) | created(date)
```

You can index the sorting key wiht somethig like:

```
id    | version      | data         | created 
01    | 'v00000'     | {latestData} | ...latestTimeStamp 
01    | 'v00001'     | { someData } | ...someTimeStamp 
01    | 'v00002'     | { someData } | ...someTimeStamp 
02    | 'v00000'     | {latestData} | ...latestTimeStamp
02    | 'v00001'     | { someData } | ...someTimeStamp
```

When you'll insert the 01 - v00003 data, you'll overwrite the v00000 too.

Doing this, when you get the ID + v00000 you have always the latest data of your id.

Hope it helps.